# why tracert does not show the same gateway address as in ipconfig

Tags: route, networking

I am confused by the following:

```
C:\>ipconfig
....
        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : some address here
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.77.121.54
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.77.121.1
```

From the above, the gateway for my pc is 10.77.121.1. But when I use the tracert, the first IP address is different as you can see from the following. It is 10.77.121.3. Why?

```
C:\tracert 10.75.89.100

Tracing route to 10.75.89.100
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    29 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.77.121.3
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.77.0.34
  3     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.77.0.45
  4    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.75.89.100
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the gateway you're using may be using [VRRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Router_Redundancy_Protocol) or [HSRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Standby_Router_Protocol). 10.77.121.1 is a virtual/logical address, which you use as your gateway, but when you trace route one of the physical routers responds. (10.77.121.3)

Answer (score 2):

> From the above, the gateway for my pc is 10.77.121.1. But when I use the tracert, the first IP address is different as you can see from the following. It is 10.77.121.3. Why?

It is rare, but perhaps 10.77.121.1 no longer has a connection to the next hop, but it still has forwarding enabled.  If this is the case, with some operating systems, when you attempt to send a packet you will contact 10.77.121.1, but 10.77.121.1 will return an [ICMP redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Redirect_Message) with 10.77.121.3 as the address your system be using as a gateway.  Since your packet is not actually being forwarded by 10.77.121.1 it wouldn't show up in a trace route.

A quick capture with your favorite sniffer on your client would confirm that this is happening.

ICMP redirects are mostly discouraged these days for security reasons, so having a setup like this is uncommon.

[image: Network Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Your default gateway isn't always the next hop. In fact it is generally the router of last resort. Your computer will parse the routing table and will only use the default gateway if no other more specific routes match. So do a **route print** and see what you find there.

Answer (score 1):

In my enterprise, the gateways are all redundant.  From host side we set gateway to be 192.168.0.1, but that's a load-balanced IP managed by two routers who are actually 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3.  When you traceroute, the outbound packet goes to destination x.x.x.1, but the IGMP reply packet comes from x.x.x.2 or x.x.x.3 depending on which router is active.  traceroute shows the IGMP originating address.

Answer (score 0):

It could be @MikeR's answer. It could also be that your machine has a route to the 10.75.89.100 address that doesn't go through the default gateway, but instead goes through 10.77.121.3. Check your host's routing table to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. I am using Sonicwall device in between. Some firewall settings blocked it from showing the IP in tracert.

For this Please login to DELL SONICWALL --> Firewall Settings -->Advanced

there enable check against Decrement IP TTL for forwarded traffic under Detection Prevention and test it and let me know is that is help full.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ryan and I think your computer is parsing your routing table and that's why it's not sending you to default gateway.
You can use this to flush your route table:

```
sudo ip route flush table main
```

Then you can again run this to make sure your route table is empty:

```
route -n
```

Now you can reset your internet so that your route table gets default values, and your problem will be solved.